# How can I add a "%" to all values in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

If I simply add a % to the value it won't work. How can I add % to all the values?

```
 var chartData = {
"barCircleMobile":[
    {"index":0.3, "value":100, "fill":"#37b54e", "label":"WebMd Health"},
    {"index":0.4, "value":50, "fill":"#69dad9", "label":"Livestrong.com"},
    {"index":0.5, "value":31.25, "fill":"#00a8dd", "label":"Everyday 
Health"},
    {"index":0.6, "value":18.75,  "fill":"#157996", "label":"About.com"},
    {"index":0.7, "value":6.5,  "fill":"#0068ff", "label":"Drugs.com"},

],
"barCircleWeb":[
    {"index":0.3, "value":100, "fill":"#20d974", "label":"WebMD Health"},
    {"index":0.4, "value":40, "fill":"#3bc1c4", "label":"Everyday Health"},
    {"index":0.5, "value":30, "fill":"#23889d", "label":"Livestrong.com"},
    {"index":0.6, "value":20, "fill":"#0071a3", "label":"About.com Health 
Section"},
    {"index":0.7, "value":10, "fill":"#0042a3", "label":"Healthline"},
]
};

function drawBarCircleChart(data,target,values,labels){
var w = 362,
    h = 362,
    size = data[0].value * 1,
    radius = 200,
    sectorWidth = .1,
    radScale = 25,
    sectorScale = 1.75,
    target = d3.select(target),
    valueText = d3.select(values),
    labelText = d3.select(labels);


var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(function(d,i){return (d.index/sectorScale) * radius + 
radScale; })
    .outerRadius(function(d,i){return ((d.index/sectorScale) + 
 (sectorWidth/sectorScale)) * radius + radScale; })
    .startAngle(Math.PI)
    .endAngle(function(d) { return Math.PI + (d.value / size) * 2 * Math.PI; 
 });

var path = target.selectAll("path")
    .data(data);

//TODO: seperate color and index from data object, make it a pain to update 
object order
path.enter().append("svg:path")
    .attr("fill",function(d,i){return d.fill})
    .transition()
    .ease("elastic")
    .duration(1000)
    .delay(function(d,i){return i*100})
    .attrTween("d", arcTween);

valueText.selectAll("tspan").data(data).enter()
    .append("tspan")
    .attr({
        x:50,
        y:function(d,i){return i*14},       
        "text-anchor":"end"
    })
    .text(function(d,i){return data[i].value});

labelText.selectAll("tspan").data(data).enter()
    .append("tspan")
    .attr({
        x:0,
        y:function(d,i){return i*14}
    })
    .text(function(d,i){return data[i].label});

function arcTween(b) {
    var i = d3.interpolate({value: 0}, b);
    return function(t) {
        return arc(i(t));
    };
}
}

// Animation Queue
setTimeout(function(){drawBarCircleChart(chartData.barCircleWeb,"#circleBar- 
web-chart","#circleBar-web-values","#circleBar-web-labels")},500);
setTimeout(function() 
{drawBarCircleChart(chartData.barCircleMobile,"#circleBar-mobile- 
chart","#circleBar-mobile-values","#circleBar-mobile-labels")},800);

 d3.select("#circleBar-web-icon")
.transition()
.delay(500)
.duration(500)
.attr("opacity","1");
 d3.select("#circleBar-web-text")
.transition()
.delay(750)
.duration(500)
.attr("opacity","1");

d3.select("#circleBar-web-clipLabels")
.transition()
.delay(600)
.duration(1250)
.attr("height","150");

d3.select("#circleBar-mobile-icon")
.transition()
.delay(800)
.duration(500)
.attr("opacity","1");
d3.select("#circleBar-mobile-text")
.transition()
.delay(1050)
.duration(500)
.attr("opacity","1");
d3.select("#circleBar-mobile-clipLabels")
.transition()
.delay(900)
.duration(1250)
.attr("height","150");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add '%' in your text return,

```
valueText.selectAll("tspan").data(data).enter()
    .append("tspan")
    .attr({
        x:50,
        y:function(d,i){return i*14},       
        "text-anchor":"end"
    })
    .text(function(d,i){return data[i].value +'%' });
```

I hope it helps you